# Can we fire javascript function when user type something using mobile keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically some javascript function get executed on my page that avoid me to type anything in input field using mobile keyboard.

So, Is there any way to detect whether user is tying using mobile ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent typing using the mobile keyboard, or are you trying to figure out what's preventing you from using the mobile keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the way

```js
$("input").on('focus', function(){
  if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // fire the function
}
})
```

Thanks @Jyothi for the code to detect mobile

Answer (score 1):

You can use `javascript` to detect mobile as below

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // code to disable your form or hide your form from editing
}
```

Comment: thanks,  this will detect mobile but i want to fire javascript function at the time  when user (focus on input) type something using mobile keyboard

Comment: Actually the problem is : i am using bootstrap tour and when user focus on input using mobile the tour get refresh . this prevent user to type inside the input box ,so i wanted to stop that refresh. I found another solution for this issue, thanks anyway :)